# Next/Previous button for nodes within a book

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, navigation

I want to have Next and Back buttons for nodes within a book.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: nodes in a book already have previous and next links, along with Up ... cant you theme those to your needs ?

Comment: yes, what is the best way to theme them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this can be achieved by overriding of modules\books\book-navigation.tpl file. Copy this file to your Theme and change following:

```
 <?php if ($has_links): ?>
    <div class="page-links clearfix">
      <?php if ($prev_url): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $prev_url; ?>" class="page-previous" title="<?php print t('Go to previous page'); ?>"><?php print t('‹ ') . $prev_title; ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($parent_url): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $parent_url; ?>" class="page-up" title="<?php print t('Go to parent page'); ?>"><?php print t('up'); ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($next_url): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $next_url; ?>" class="page-next" title="<?php print t('Go to next page'); ?>"><?php print $next_title . t(' ›'); ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if ($has_links): ?>
    <div class="page-links clearfix">
      <?php if ($prev_url): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $prev_url; ?>" class="page-previous" title="<?php print t('Go to previous page'); ?>"><?php print t('Back') ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($parent_url): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $parent_url; ?>" class="page-up" title="<?php print t('Go to parent page'); ?>"><?php print t('up'); ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($next_url): ?>
        <a href="<?php print $next_url; ?>" class="page-next" title="<?php print t('Go to next page'); ?>"><?php print t('Next'); ?></a>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try one of the following modules: http://drupal.org/project/prev_next or http://drupal.org/project/custom_pagers. We've been using the Prev/Next module for a while in a project.

Comment: this is sort of interesting, but custom_pages is only for D6 and prev_next gets next node by node id, not by it's location in a Book.

Comment: custom_pages has a dev drupal 7 version, might look into that, as it uses views. But I'm not sure what you mean by a book, is it a view? taxonomy? More context would help.

Comment: Book is a module in core that allows to join nodes in hierarchical structure. It also adds navigation links to Up/Next/Prev, but text in the link to a next node has a name of the node, while I just need "Next" button/link.

Comment: Well, you should have been more clear on that! You can just theme the existing ones (theme is book_navigation).

Comment: well there is books tag on the question